# Could we have an option to resize pictures after post?

Tags: feature-request, design

I think more than 80% all pictures in this Q&A are screen shots from phone.

As the average size is 840x480 and now we even have giant phones with more than 1024 px height is becoming difficult to the community to post them and still make them pleasant to read.

Take a look at this: [Re-arrange Cortana's glance items](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/3526/re-arrange-cortanas-glance-items)

It would be great if some options to resize pictures were in place.

Answer (score 3):

Currently the maximum width of images is 630px (all.css → `.post-text img` rule). With a 15:9 aspect ratio this gives a height of 1050px; at 16:9 it's 1120px.

Assuming SE allows this level of customisation for the individual sites, the simplest solution would be to simply decrease the default max-width of images. 400px seems to be a reasonable compromose - not too big, but text is still legible. If you want to try it out for yourself, most modern browsers should have integrated developer tools that can modify stylesheets on the fly, launched by pressing <kbd>F12</kbd> (in some browsers you can also right-click on a screenshot and select "Inspect").

Resize options would be nice to have as well, but if the majority of screenshots are going to be in portrait rather than landscape (which is the case with smartphones), it seems to me that an automatic solution that doesn't require every image to be resized individually would be a better option.

Just my two cents.

---

Alternatively, images can already be resized, you'll simply have to use HTML instead of Markdown. So instead of this:

```
![enter image description here][1]

 [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/foobar
```

Use something like this:

```
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/foobar" width="400">
```

Example: [What exactly is needed to activate Cortana?](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/3521/1401) (just edited the question to make the screenshot smaller)

Further, if the screenshot contains a lot of detail, you can also make it link to the full-size version (with an optional footnote at the end):

```
<a href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/foobar"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/foobar" width="400"></a>  
<sup>(Click for full-size version)</sup>
```

This is of course probably a bit much to expect from new users, but at least it's something that can be done right now about posts where the size of the screenshots is especially problematic.

Comment: I knew about the html markup but almost nobody care to use. And if you mistakenly use ‘400px’ instead of just ‘400’ it will not work. Better than nothing